# Osx 10.11 set path for gui launched applications

Tags: macos, path, osx-elcapitan, finder

I want to get sublime to directly connect to gams.

`Gams` is set up right in the terminal and `launchctl`

```
 gams --version
--- Job --version Start 05/12/16 09:09:32 24.7.1 r56632 DEX-DEG x86 64bit/MacOS X
*** Unable to open input file (RC=2) --version
*** SysMsg: No such file or directory
*** Status: Terminated due to parameter errors
--- Job --version Stop 05/12/16 09:09:32 elapsed 0:00:00.001
which gams
/Applications/gams/gams24.7_osx_x64_64_sfx/gams
launchctl getenv gams
/Applications/gams/gams24.7_osx_x64_64_sfx
```

However sublime does not seem to pick up the `$PATH` even tough it is setup up via launchtl.
[image: gams not found]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case edit the sublime-gams configuration file:

"path": "/Applications/GAMS/gams24.7_osx_x64_64_sfx",

and set the path there.